# Prostaglandin F2-alpha production in men

Tags: endocrinology

I am trying to find information on Prostaglandin F2-alpha, specificaly production in men. Could somebody explain how this prostaglandin is produced? What types of cells are producing it, production signaling? Any books on this subject?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I know:

One of the most important chemical mediators are prostaglandins that in vivo act on different cell receptors and have different effects on the body. Prostaglandins are twenty-carbon lipid molecules and structurally similar to cholesterol. Prostaglandins have different types, such as F2, E2 alpha, PGI2, and so on.

A phospholipase enzyme converts phospholipids of cell membranes into arachidonic acid. The arachidonic acid within the cyclooxygenase enzyme or Cox (both type 1 and 2) can be converted to prostaglandins.

PGF2alpha has functions in uterus contraction and bronchoconstriction, so I think both uterus and lung cells produce it.

I have no special information about production of PGF2alpha in men.

Comment: I think it is incorrect to say that prostaglandins are structurally similar to cholesterol.

Answer (score 1):

PubChem is a good resource for finding out more about compounds of pharmaceutical interest:

http://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/summary/summary.cgi?cid=5280363

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer to the question. To make it an answer you should pick out some key points from the article and include them in your post.